# Jquery-ui autocomplete multiple instances

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui

Hi I have multiple jQuery-UI autocomplete instances running on a single page.

```
<div id="div1">
<input name= "city[1]" class= "city" id="city1" />
<select name = "select1" class = "zipcodes" id = "zipcodes1"></select>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<input name= "city[2]" class= "city" id="city2" />
<select name = "select2" class = "zipcodes" id = "zipcodes2"></select>
</div>
```

These fields are added by javascript. The autocomplete works well for the inputs. The callback populates the zipcodes field options.

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
    $($(".city").sibling("zipcodes")).empty();
    $.each(ui.item.zip, function(Index, Value){
         // Populate the zipcodes fields
        });
        }
```

The problem is that it populates *all* the zipcode fields on the page

I tried using

```
(".city").autocomplete( "widget" )
```

to select the particular autocomplete being queried, but it still populates all the fields.

How do I identify the particular field being queried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).sibling(".zipcodes").empty();

       $.each(ui.item.zip, function(Index, Value){
         // Populate the zipcodes fields
           $(this).sibling(".zipcodes") .......
        });
        }
```

Comment: That causes the entire callback to break- no fields are populated

Comment: Ok the silent fail was because function populating the select box was within another callback & '$(this)' was therefore not in the right context. Assigning $(this) to a variable solved the silent fail. The switch to $(this) worked afterall. Thanks